# React reference to nested state item when updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

My `state` looks like this:

```
brands:[{key:'0', cars:[]}, {key:'2', cars:[]}, {key:'3', cars:[]}]
```

Each `car` array is in the form:

```
[{key:'0', color:'Red', detail:''}, {key:'1', color:'Green', detail:''}]
```

I map each brand list to a component `<Brand cars={brand.cars}>`

Each brand maps it's cars to:

`<Car color={car.color} detail:"" fetchDetailCallback={this.carDetailCallback}>`

When a car is clicked, the fetchDetailCallback callback is called on the parent which fetches further details about the car from my database.

How do I then update the state to fill in these details?

```
function carDetailCallback(brandKey, carKey){
   //fetch detail from database code here

   this.setState({brands[brandKey][carKey]: detail})
}
```

Of course `this.setState({'sentences'[brandKey][carKey]: detail})` does not work because the keys are not real keys, they are the names of name-value pairs within arrays.

How should I reference the correct `Car` in the state in order to update it?

Do I have to search through the Brands to find the one with the matching Key, and then search through the Cars in that Brand to find the one with the matching CarKey and then replace the whole Brand with this.setState() once I update it? This seems like a long way of updating a value in the state.

Comment: Since you are using React, you must be using babel. Try `{ [sentences[brandKey][carKey]]: detail }`

Comment: I mean to say that the keys do not work this way in the state's data structure so how do I find and update the correct "car" in the state.

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html  Just search for reducers composition. Probably this will help you to understand it

Comment: Thanks but it was recommended to me to learn to build my React app without Redux first and then learn that after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the specific brand and car object  and [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find index of an item to update.

**Example**

```
const data = { brands:[{key:'0', cars:[{key:'0', color:'Red', detail:''}, {key:'1', color:'Green', detail:''}]}, {key:'2', cars:[{key:'0', color:'Red', detail:''}, {key:'1', color:'Green', detail:''}]}] };

const brand = data.brands.find((brand) => brand.key === brandKey);
const car = brand.cars.find((car) => car.key === carKey);

const brandIndex = data.brands.findIndex((brand) => brand.key === brandKey);
const carIndex = brand.cars.findIndex((car) => car.key === carKey);

this.setState({ brands[brandIndex][carIndex]['details']: details });
```

Comment: Does this just extract the car object from the array? How do I get a pointer to update it in the state?